# Converting lambda(int)->int to std::function<int(float)>

Tags: c++, g++, c++17

Why C++ compiler doesn't give warning or error for this code?

```
    std::function<int(float)> f = [](int x) -> int {
        return x*x;
    };

    std::cout << f(4.2) << '\n';
```

Is there a way to prevent this kind of implicit conversations? (to write a wrapper or a helper methods for example to generate an error)

Comment: Which compiler are you using and which options did you try?

Comment: Storing `[](int)->int` into `std::function<int(float)>` doesn't make the initial `lambda [](float)->int`.

Comment: You can check `operator()` (have a callable traits), but would not work for generic lambda or custom functor with overloaded `operator()`.

Comment: using a wrapper would require you to explicitly use the wrapper, but not prevent your code as is to compile. I guess I just dont get it, but can you show an example of what would be "ok" for you to write instead?

Comment: @Damien I use G++10 with no options, Is there a flag to enable to give warnings for this?

Comment: @Damien for your particular case, MSVC gives a comprehensive warning on warning level 4 at least (for 32Bit environment). For gcc, -Wconversion would be the way but it doesn't seem to work here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why C++ compiler doesn't give warning or error for this code?

The compiler option for gcc for cases of this category is commonly `-Wconversion`, but it doesn't seem to work for your particular case. I tried a lot of other flags but without success. You can obtain a comprehensive warning with MSVC on warning level 4 for this however.

Why should it give an error? It would be contradictory to one main purpose of `std::function`, namely to benefit from allowed implicit conversions in order to stay flexible as a general functor holder and in doubt, you're able to make things more explicit on your own via signature checker traits. For `std::function`, that could look like this ("old" pre-C++17 approach, some drawbacks with generic Lambdas and overloads, see comments):

```
template <typename ProvidedSignature, typename RequiredSignature>
struct SignatureMatches :  std::false_type
{};

template <typename R1, typename R2>
struct SignatureMatches<R1(), R2()> : std::is_convertible<R2, R1>
{};

template <typename R1, typename R2, typename Arg1, typename Arg2, typename... Args1, typename... Args2>
struct SignatureMatches<R1(Arg1, Args1...), R2(Arg2, Args2...)>
  : std::conditional_t<
      std::is_convertible_v<std::remove_cv_t<std::remove_reference_t<Arg1>>, std::remove_cv_t<std::remove_reference_t<Arg2>>>,
      SignatureMatches<R1(Args1...), R2(Args2...)>,
      std::false_type>
{};

template <typename R1, typename R2, typename... Args1, typename... Args2>
struct SignatureMatches<R1(Args1...) noexcept, R2(Args2...) noexcept>
  : SignatureMatches<R1(Args1...), R2(Args2...)>
{};
```

For your own purposes, you just would have to change

```
std::is_convertible_v<std::remove_cv_t<std::remove_reference_t<Arg1>>, std::remove_cv_t<std::remove_reference_t<Arg2>>>
```

to a stricter scheme, maybe via `std::is_same`.

Also see the standard's definition and requirements for callable objects: [Callable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Callable)

Comment: Tagged as C++17, so you might use fold expression instead of recursion.

Comment: Issues are with overloads, generic lambda.